# Significant change location not trigger in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c

Significant change location service not trigger on iPhone 7 plus but it  work on other devices. please help ... .
 I have tried following code

```
[appDelegate.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
 appDelegate.locationManager=nil;
 appDelegate.locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
 if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
    {
        [appDelegate.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    if ([appDelegate.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [appDelegate.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        //flag=1;
    }


    appDelegate.locationManager.delegate = appDelegate.self;
    if(IS_OS_9_OR_LATER) {
        appDelegate.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates=YES;
    }
    //appDelegate.locationManager
appDelegate.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
           appDelegate.locationManager.distanceFilter = 200;


    //locationManager.activityType=CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation;
    appDelegate.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=NO;
    [appDelegate.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

This Code not works on iPhone 7 plus but works on other devices and iOS 10 OS.

Comment: If i remember correctly the distanceFilter is pretty much ignored for significant location changes, since the minimum location change is a gsm cell, which is around 500 meters. May be useful for testing.

Comment: i tried it but its not works.